# Rename DOS command

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to rename the files with names as `1_2_result.bak` to `1.txt`.
I tried with command `rename *_result.bak *.txt`, but only .bat to .txt is getting done. Can anyone suggest how to change the file names?
and even ren ?_result.txt ?.c does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ren ?_result.bak ?.txt
```

`?` matches a single character. Use `??` for two-digit files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is an option for you, but a different shell (alternative for cmd.exe), **4NT** is freely available nowadays, and iirc it also supports renames with * wildcards in rename.

Seems that 4NT has been renamed to [TCLE](http://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html)